# SQL query to make 2 sums from the same field

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am trying to have the total "amount" with "type" = 1 and with type = 2 by year of the "created_at" field.

Here is the table

```
+-----------------+------------------+------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | 
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----
 | id              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | 

 | type            | int(10) unsigned | YES  |

 | type            | varchar(255)     | NO   | 
| amount          | double(11,2)     | NO   |                           
| created_at      | timestamp        | YES  |
| updated_at      | timestamp        | YES  |
```

Here is my code (It only gives the total for type = 1):

```
DB::select(
        'SELECT 
                year, 
                created_at,
                type,
                SUM(amount) AS total
          FROM 
              (SELECT 
                YEAR(created_at) AS year, 
                amount, 
                created_at, 
                type 
              FROM table 
              WHERE type= 1) AS t 
          GROUP BY year, type
          ORDER BY year;
    ');
```

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't think you need a subquery for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you really want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT YEAR(created_at) AS year, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as amount_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as amount_2
FROM table 
GROUP BY YEAR(created_at);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need one simple query for this.  Take the year of the date, sum the amount and group by year and type.  FYI, you have `type` as a field twice in your question.  That's not possible, so I'm assuming that it's really some other field name the second time.

```
SELECT
    YEAR(created_at) AS year, 
    type,
    SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY YEAR(created_at), type
ORDER BY YEAR(created_at)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a2a45/1)

Answer (score -1):

Your question needs more clarification but I assumed you wanted to compare type 1 amount per year,created at, type to the total yearly amount.

```
select year(created_at), created_at, type,
       sum(case when type =1 then amount else 0 end) as type1amount,
       sum(amount) over (partition by year(created_at)) as yeartotal
from table
group by 1,2,3
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I got the solution right before you by Gordon Linoff